# Prevent type detection upon opening a CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

**Old:** With the following VBA Code *(removed)* I can open a CSV file with dates and numbers automatically detected and formatted. How can I keep all cells as raw text?

**Reason**: I want to compare the CSV entries with another table formatted as text, which I don't want to edit.

**New:** With the following VBA Code as suggested in the comments and taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text), a CSV test file

```
"Value1";"Value2";"Value3"
"1,0";"2,0";"3,0"
```

is split into

[image]

Why? My windows regional setting is German (Germany).

```
Sub OpenCSV()

  Dim sourceWs As Worksheet

  sourceFile = CStr( _
    Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="CSV-Dateien (*.csv),*.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=False _
    ) _
  )
  
  OpenCsvAsText sourceFile
End Sub



Sub OpenCsvAsText(ByVal strFilepath As String)

    Dim intFileNo As Integer
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim nCol As Long
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim varColumnFormat As Variant
    Dim varTemp As Variant

    '// Read first line of file to figure out how many columns there are
    intFileNo = FreeFile()
    Open strFilepath For Input As #intFileNo
    Line Input #intFileNo, strLine
    Close #intFileNo
    varTemp = Split(strLine, ";")
    nCol = UBound(varTemp) + 1

    '// Prepare description of column format
    ReDim varColumnFormat(0 To nCol - 1)
    For iCol = 1 To nCol
        varColumnFormat(iCol - 1) = Array(iCol, xlTextFormat)
        ' What's this? See VBA help for OpenText method (FieldInfo argument).
    Next iCol

    '// Open the file using the specified column formats
    Workbooks.OpenText _
            Filename:=strFilepath, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Comma:=False, _
            Semicolon:=True, _
            FieldInfo:=varColumnFormat, _
            TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote

End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text

Comment: Use the Workbook.OpenText method and set all the columns to text type.

Comment: Even with "Comma:=False" and "Semicolon:=True" OpenText doesn't split my CSV at semicolons but at commas, any idea why this might be the case? With "Local:=True" it works but dates keep being dates...

Comment: Edit your question to provide a sample of data **as text** which can be copy/pasted. Include your Windows Regional Settings information. Also, **why** do you want the dates retained as text and not interpreted as ***real dates***?

Comment: Done. Hope you can reproduce it!

Comment: Apologies for forgetting this. `Workbooks.OpenText` method requires that the file be a *.txt* file. Your code should work, but you will need to rename  or copy `sourceFile` and act on the new file:  `FileCopy sourceFile, sourceFile & ".txt"`.

Comment: You should also consider using Power Query to import the csv file -- I'm not sure if it is part of Excel 2013, or if you need to download the free Microsoft add-in for that version. Look for `Get&Transform` on the `Data` tab to check. Finally, if you are comparing two csv files, and looking for the differences, it may be simpler to use the `FileSystemObject` and do a line-by-line compare; or the `WshSHell` object with the `fc` command (under VBA)

Comment: Finally, the `QueryTables.Add` method can also be used without the need of renaming the  csv file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Indeed, converted to .txt it works. I already have a Power Query that produces a table whose entries I'm processing using VBA. I would like to include the CSV access into the VBA script to avoid the additional worksheet produced by the query... Not sure yet if it's worth it or a stupid idea to duplicate and delete the CSV every time :)